# Como agregarle un anchor (<a></a>) a una palabra en particular si todo el texto viene desde una db como mongo?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Estoy creando un blog en Next.js y moongose, cuando hago fetch de un dato desde la db

```
const blog = await fetchBlog(searchParams.id.trim());
```

Estoy obteniendo los datos ya formateados, tiene un campo description el cual trae un texto largo, ahora cuando lo muestro en el front seria asi:

```
<p>{blog.description}</p>
```

justo como en react...la pregunta es si yo quiero acceder a una palabra en particular que viene en ese texto para agregarle un anchor o una negrita, como lo hago?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por ejemplo todo este texto es {blog.description} y necesito acceder a una palabra para envolverla en un anchor....

Comment: ¿Con qué estás trabajando en el front? ¿JS puro? ¿Algún framework/librería?

Comment: estoy trabajando con Next.js 13 y mongoose, en el front con un flowite para los componentes

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si estas seguro que el texto de la base de datos no contiene contenido ni caracteres que pueda ser dañino para la página. Puedes usar la propiedad `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

Tomas el texto de la base de datos, reemplazas o generas el link como quieras (como si fuera html normal) y luego lo muestras con esa propiedad.

```js
const {useState,useEffect} = React;

function App(props) {

  const valorDb = "Este es un texto desde la base de datos con un link al principio y otro link al final";
  //generas el <a> con la palabra "link"
  const data = valorDb.split("link").join('<a href="http://www.google.com">link</a>');
  return (
    <div>
      <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: data}}></p>
    </div>
  );
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render( <App/>)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: perfecto, entiendo lo que hiciste, pero tengo un dilema y es que estoy modularizando, y el texto que viene de la db va a cambiar por cada item, osea que el texto va a ser distinto y asi tambien la url de los links deberia cambiar por cada texto, o palabra clave que quiera utilizar

Comment: Si quieres crea otra pregunta con ese caso especifico y con el código relevante para poder ayudarte